# How to keep the last character always visible in an input field on mobile safari?

Tags: jquery-mobile, mobile-safari, iphone-web-app

I've a mobile web app and in it I've an input field type text.

I'm assigning it's value as

```
function setVal(str){
    var item = $('#textField'),
        string = item.val()+str; 
    item.val(string);
}
```

As the value is set programmaticaly without focusing on the field and typing on a keyboard, as the `string` gets longer than the width of the text-field, I can no longer see the new character additions as the text-field masks it.

[image]

You can see in the image above, the right most letter is 'K' (after j) but only part of it is visible.

How do I make sure that if the length of the string is more than the width of the text-field, the extra length goes left ward and the last letter is visible on the screen all the time?

Answer (score 0):

Not exatly what you're looking for, but you can scroll left the text inside equally to the length of the input text, so the last character can always be visible.

```js
var el = document.getElementById('textField');
el.focus();
el.scrollLeft = el.scrollWidth;
```

```html
<input id="textField"></input>
```